# Remove dictionary from list if two dictionaries have duplicate keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am still not too familiar with list composition and stuff so I appreciate the help.

I have a list of dictionaries which contain a url and a number in each dictionary like so:

```
data = [{'url': 'www.url1.com', 'max': '14.6'},
        {'url': 'www.url2.com', 'max': '17.8'},
        {'url': 'www.url2.com', 'max': '18.4'},
        {'url': 'www.url3.com', 'max': '15.5'}]
```

I would like to filter out any dictionaries with a duplicate `url` key even if the `max` key is different from the other duplicate entry.

My expected result would be:

```
data = [{'url': 'www.url1.com', 'max': '14.6'},
        {'url': 'www.url2.com', 'max': '17.8'},
        {'url': 'www.url3.com', 'max': '15.5'}]
```

I have tried quite a few things but none of it is close enough to post here in order to fix.

I appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a dictionary comprehension then get the values of it then convert it into a list:

```
data = [{'url': 'www.url1.com', 'max': '14.6'},
        {'url': 'www.url2.com', 'max': '17.8'},
        {'url': 'www.url2.com', 'max': '18.4'},
        {'url': 'www.url3.com', 'max': '15.5'}]
print(list({v['url']:v for v in data}.values()))
```

Output:

```
[{'url': 'www.url1.com', 'max': '14.6'}, {'url': 'www.url2.com', 'max': '18.4'}, {'url': 'www.url3.com', 'max': '15.5'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [`toolz.unique`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique). If you don't have this 3rd party library, you can use the equivalent `unique_everseen` [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from toolz import unique
from operator import itemgetter

res = list(unique(data, key=itemgetter('url')))

print(res)

[{'url': 'www.url1.com', 'max': '14.6'},
 {'url': 'www.url2.com', 'max': '17.8'},
 {'url': 'www.url3.com', 'max': '15.5'}]
```

Comment: Nice man thank you, that works perfectly for my needs. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

For a pure python method:

```
data = [{'url': 'www.url1.com', 'max': '14.6'},
        {'url': 'www.url2.com', 'max': '17.8'},
        {'url': 'www.url2.com', 'max': '18.4'},
        {'url': 'www.url3.com', 'max': '15.5'}]

seen_before = []
for d in data:
    if d['url'] not in seen_before:
        seen_before.append(d['url'])
print(seen_before)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple function below would satisfy your needs.

```
def clean_data(data):
    new_data = []
    urls = [] 
    for rec in data:
        rec_url = rec.get("url")
        if not rec_url in urls:
            urls.append(rec_url)
            new_data.append(rec)
        else:
            pass
    return new_data

clean_data(data)
```